When stringing a cigar box guitar, how does A, D, G correspond to G, D, G?
I have built a cigar box guitar. This is a 'learn by doing' project, so I came into it knowing nothing about either music or building things. From that perspective, it's been a successful project, but it does mean I have to ask what may be stupid questions...
So, anyway... as for what strings to use, I found an answer on Quora that seems like it would be correct. They say to use the "5th, 4th, and 3rd strings from an acoustic guitar set." This would be the A, D, and G strings (Eugene Ate Dynamite, Good Bye Eugene,) but they say that this is open-G tuning, which is the bog-standard common tuning for CBGs. But in open-G tuning, the 1st string is G, the second string is D, and the third string is G.
So, how do the A, D, and G strings produce G, D, G tuning? Can you perhaps tune the A string to G by winding it tighter or something? What am I missing?

I know very little about cigar box guitars and their tunings so I will just comment. It sounds like that info may be displaced. Actually the 4th, 3rd and 2nd strings, or DGB strings on a guitar form an open G chord. If you were to use 3-2-1 you would have GBE and if you tune the E down to a D you have a G open tuning, GBD. I think using 5-4–3 of a 6 string set (which you could tune GDG or BDG for open G) would produce a very low pitched sound for a 3 string guitar.

How long is your cigar box guitar? This is important when choosing proper strings.

You can tune an A string to G by winding it less tight (assuming same length).
Tighter wound string produces higher pitch; looser string - lower pitch. (That's what tuning a guitar is all about - tightening the strings just right for each to make the desired tone.) G is two semitones below A.
It has limits, so don't think of the strings as interchangeable, but going two semitones down from a string's standard pitch is within. (In contrast, you really shouldn't try to wind an A string all the way up to the G that's almost an octave above.)

You can think about it like this. The string does not know what tone to produce. It is placed on the instrument and tensioned, and how tight it is defines the tone it will produce. In theory you can use any string in any position, but in some positions a given string will  have to be very tight and in some very loose. In addition the quality of the tone will be different using different gauges of strings or wound / not wound in the same position. The best one to use in each position is partly dependant on taste (electric guitar strings come in sets often named after the top string).

@ghellquist Don't know about you but I don't have theoretical infinitely elastic strings on my guitar. I have real strings of steel, with the whole stress-strain curve of the material. Set them way too loose, they just rattle against the frets instead of making any tone. Set them way too tight, they're likely to break and if they don't, they may damage the instrument. The string is made so that it works best for one given pitch, from which you can get a little way elsewhere but not too far. And what they're made for spans a factor of 4 in frequency across the set. That's some difference.

A, D and G are not open G tuning. They're not any open tuning.
Open tuning presumes all strings together produce a specific chord. Chord G consists of G, B and D, in any order you like. Or it could be simply G and D.  What tuning you like for any guitar is somewhat dependant on the string gauges used - too loose or too tight makes playing awkward to say the least. Any string can be tuned to + /- a tone or so, before it reaches that point, but to have all strings at approximately the same tension is best.
There are several (many) different options for tuning, which won't help answer your question, but you'll have to decide which you prefer, and use appropriate fingering for chords accordingly. If you feel one string is too loose, change it for a heavier gauge, if it's too tight, get a lighter gauge string.
Unfortunately, the feel will only come with experience, which you lack at present. So decide on one of the many options, try that, and see/hear what happens. Just don't tighten anything too much, otherwise it's down to CBG mk ii!

"Not any"? Does Dsus4 not count as an open tuning?

@Divizna - not in my book, sorry! Using that logic, one could take any triad, any three notes, and call it an open chord, from open tuning. Which wouldn't make a lot of sense.
